# Is there a way to see what character set was used to export an Oracle dump (dmp) file, using a text editor?

Tags: oracle, import, export

Is there a way to see what character set was used to export an Oracle dump (dmp) file using a text editor?

I know I can see the Oracle version in the .dmp file - it is displayed in cleartext.

But, can I see the character set?  It doesn't appear to be in cleartext anywhere, but I'm guessing it's in there 'somewhere', perhaps as HEX?

The reason I ask is that I receive a message regarding a potential conflict between the import server character set and the character set in the .dmp file when trying to import it.  The warning, however, does not show me the *export* character set.  it says *'Import'* against both, which I think is a misleading message - hence wanting to check the .dmp file for the info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is export:

```
E:\>exp scott/tiger@orcl file=scott.dmp

Export: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Wed Mar 11 11:49:56 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Productio
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Tes
Export done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
server uses EE8MSWIN1250 character set (possible charset conversion)
. exporting pre-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting foreign function library names for user SCOTT
EXP-00091: Exporting questionable statistics.
. . exporting table                            EMP         14 rows exported
<snip>
. exporting statistics
Export terminated successfully with warnings.
```

The result is `scott.dmp` file. If you use `show=y` import's option, nothing will be imported, but you'll see list of exported objects. You're interested in the first several lines:

```
E:\>imp scott/tiger@orcl file=scott.dmp show=y

Import: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Wed Mar 11 11:50:17 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Tes

Export file created by EXPORT:V11.02.00 via conventional path
import done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses EE8MSWIN1250 character set (possible charset conversion)
. importing SCOTT's objects into SCOTT
 "BEGIN  "
<snip>
```

I guess you see character sets mentioned, don't you? Hopefully, it'll help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Does one of these lines identify the character set used for export?
`import done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set` OR 
`import server uses EE8MSWIN1250 character set (possible charset conversion)`
They both specify 'Import'